# Building a menu based on user authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have an entity project from another application that is being brought into a new MVC web app.  I would like the web users to have access to only certain instances of a few of the entities.  For example, we have four tiers of organizing entities: Company, Site, Project, Package.  I want user X to have access to two of the companies, some of the sites under those companies and so on.

I currently have the Identity related database schema added to our database that hosts the entities, and Identity is working without problem.  What I am having a problem with is hooking up the User to the other entities.  I have junction tables the sit between User and entity tables (e.g. Users_Companies).  These junction tables unfortunately cannot be used by EF to handle relationships between User and Entity since they are in different projects and use separate contexts.

I hoped to alleviate this by using a stored proc to just return multiple result sets representing all of the entities that a user had access to, but that requires that I store the entities in DTOs since using the entity classes themselves will result in navigation properties getting all of the child entities on enumeration in the view.

How SHOULD this be done?  I have to assume that it is a relatively normal and well traversed idea to have specific instances that belong to or are viewable by specific users.  Should I just recreate my entities and put them in the Web project?  I will then have to update each copy of the entity class every time a bug fix or new feature is added.

Comment: Why dont you have a "common" project that hosts all of your entity models. Then it can be referenced by other projects to use. Or am I not understanding the problem?

Comment: @Shoe That is what we are doing in this case.  The entity project is used by both a windows application and the MVC web app.  With the entities separated from the Identity model that is in the MVC app, they can't refer to the User directly, and the User can't refer to them directly (I don't think).

Comment: Is there some restriction where you can't have them together?

Comment: @Shoe I havent found anything online so far about importing the identity functionality into an existing Entity Model.  I could move the existing entities into the MVC project, but then I would have to update two projects (the original entities and the MVC projects entities) every time a bug is fixed or a new feature is implemented in them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Identity doesn't care what models you use as long as it gets what it needs.

Comment: @Shoe I suppose I should ask what you mean by having them together and how that can be accomplished.

Comment: A single common project with all your models. You then hookup things like `Users` into Identity in your MVC project by creating your own UserStore, RoleStore etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59363/discussion-between-codewarrior-and-shoe).

Answer (score 0):

You can have your ASP.Net Identity entities defined in your "Business" project's DbContext and have something like below to get IdentityUser in your MVC app:

```
var usermanager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(new MyBusinessDbContext));
var identityUser = usermanager.FindById(myUserId);
```

Notice that `User` class is part of your `Business` project meaning you have to move `ApplicationUser` definition in your MVC project to your Business project

Comment: So, I really just need to define a class that matches the database table structure for User, Role, etc, represent them in the BusinessDbContext and instances the UserManager as above in MVC?

Comment: Yes. I believe there shouldn't be any problem

Comment: Terrific!  I will check it out in a while.  First though, gotta sleep (have been up way too long already).

Comment: One possible problem: you have to add `Microsoft.AspNet Identity` Nuget package to your Business project to let `User` derive from `IdentityUser` class to be able to use it with your MVC project's `UserManager`

Comment: Alright.  I almost have it working.  I have inherited my Entity DBContext from IdentityDbContext, ported over the ApplicationUser class and a couple of others.  I have a test method that attempts to find a user by ID, and another that logs a user in, and all of this appears to be working, but now I get a redirect loop in the login page and I am trying to figure that one out.

Comment: @CodeWarrior Thanks for the feedback. Did redirect loop problem go away?

Comment: No, I am still trying to figure it out.  First time I hit the breakpoint in Login (GET) method, returnURL is "/".  The second time, returnUrl is "/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252F", so it is feeding itself it's own url over and over again.  Still haven't figured it out though.

Comment: That's probably because your authentication cookie is not set and you're not logged in, hence it's redirecting you to the login page again. can you check that you're authenticated after the login code?